# unrecognized selector sent to class coming from Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook

Around a year ago I installed the Facebook SDK into my iOS app, solely for the purpose of ad tracking. The only SDK calls I invoke in my app are the three that they tell you to put into your app delegate. There were no issues and my app ran fine (and the ad tracking worked).

Recently Facebook sent out an email asking me to update the SDK, so I did. Now my app crashes a few seconds after launching with a string of "unrecognized selector sent to class" errors.

Since I don't have Facebook's source code, I have no way to debug this, no idea where it's coming from, and no real option other than to remove the SDK entirely from my app, which will make my marketing people very upset.

What is this problem? Has anyone found a fix?

Comment: FYI, I'm sure the problem is coming from Facebook because (a) the error message includes the text "+[NSError fbErrorWithCode:userInfo:message:underlyingError:]" and (b) the problem disappears if I comment out the three Facebook SDK calls.

Answer (score 6):

In Build Settings, do you have `-ObjC` set for "Other Linker Flags?"

That resolved the issue for me.

Also, if you're not using CocoaPods, you could [look at the podspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/0/c/0/FacebookSDK/4.38.0/FacebookSDK.podspec.json) and try making sure you've got the required dependencies linked.

Specifically:

```
  "ios": {
    "weak_frameworks": [
      "Accounts",
      "CoreLocation",
      "Social",
      "Security",
      "QuartzCore",
      "CoreGraphics",
      "UIKit",
      "Foundation",
      "AudioToolbox",
      "WebKit"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Thanks, the -ObjC flag fixed the problem for me. Apparently that was not needed in the last version.

Answer (score 0):

See [RN FBK SDK iOS issue 472](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/472) and [RN Unity SDK issue 208](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-for-unity/issues/208) also reporting similar crashes.

For me the addition of the *-ObjC* linker flag was not enough to prevent the crash.

I also had to include the *force_load* flag and the correct path to the *FBSDKLoginKit* Framework.

So in *Other Link Flags* within the project *Build Settings* in XCode I added:

```
-ObjC
-force_load
-${PROJECT_DIR}/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit
```

Note that your path to the *FBSDKCoreKit* framework may be different.

There are more details on the reason for this crash in the Github issues linked above.